# Ionic build iOS deletes changes

Tags: angularjs, xcode, ionic-framework

I have a file here:

```
/Users/myName/Desktop/KMtoMiles/platforms/ios/www/js/app.js
```

I make a change to the file using Xcode. Then I click save changes and exit Xcode. If I immediately re-enter Xcode, I can see my change is there.

Then I do the following:

```
myNameMBP:Desktop myName$ pwd
/Users/myName/Desktop
myNameMBP:Desktop myName$ ls
KMtoMiles
myNameMBP:Desktop myName$ cd KMtoMiles/
myNameMBP:KMtoMiles myName$ ionic build ios
```

Now when I open Xcode and go to app.js, my changes are no longer there.

I have had issues with permissions. I ended up just making it wide open and doing `chmod -R 777 KMtoMiles` and it appears the permissions may be changing when I do a build.

Has anyone experienced this too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ionic build iOS project automatically from the existing source, so If you need to modify any f your files go to the source and modify files there then build iOS you will get the files changed within Xcode.

-- EDIT --

So you need to edit the source files first before building your project, don't edit files directly on xcode as `ionic build ios` command will ignore your edits and replace files with the source files.

Comment: Sorry, I am not fully following you. Are you saying I don't need to do `ionic build ios` from the command line?

Comment: NO, I am saying that you need to edit the source files first before building your project, don't edit files directly on xcode as ionic build ios command will ignore your edits and replace files with the source files, if you still not understand tell me and will explain it further.

Comment: Okay, can you add this detail to your post? I will upvote with more explanation on there.